# getting 500 response in Browsershot

Tags: google-chrome, headless

I'm getting 500 response code from [browsershot package](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot)

```
<?php

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

include_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot; 

// an image will be saved
Browsershot::url('https://google.com')->save('example.pdf');
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The
>   command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node
>   '/home/www/html/developementsec.com/browsershotnew/src/../bin/browser.js'
>   '{"url":"https://google.com","action":"pdf","options":{"path":"example.pdf","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600}}}'"
>   failed. Exit Code: 8(Unknown error) Working directory:
>   /home/www/html/developementsec.com/browsershotnew Output:
>   ================ Error Output: ================ /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/cmd-list.js:113
>   module.exports.aliases = Object.assign({}, shorthands, aaffordances) ^
>   TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method
>   'assign' at Object.
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/cmd-list.js:113:33) at
>   Module._compile (module.js:456:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Module.require (modul in
>   /home/www/html/developementsec.com/browsershotnew/src/Browsershot.php
>   on line 663

Comment: Did anyone find the solution yet?